# Generate High Quality textures Realtime C++

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization, textures

I am having a procedural terrain generation application. Now i want to generate textures for the terrain based on height.

Say i have got 5 textures for different height levels now for every pixel i calculate the the position of it on the mesh then get its height and then decide which texture to sample from.

Note texture is always a square.

In code it will be something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resolution; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < resolution; j++) {
        tex[i * resolution* 3 + j * 3 + 0] = SampleTextureR(i, j);
        tex[i * resolution* 3 + j * 3 + 1] = SampleTextureG(i, j);
        tex[i * resolution* 3 + j * 3 + 2] = SampleTextureB(i, j);
    }
}
```

Now `SampleTextureR(i, j)` is just  like:

```
for(TextureData* t : txtures){
 if(t.heightl > GetMeshElevation(i, j) && t.heightg < GetMeshElevation(i, j))
  return t.sampleR(i, j);
}
return 0;
```

`GetMeshElevation` returns height of mesh at a point. t.sampleR() returns `unsigned char` value of texture's red pixels at `(i, j)`.

`heightl` is minimum height of the texture
`heightg` is maximum height of the texture

Now the problem is this this is very slow method. How can i make this fast enough to be done in realtime so that the changes to `heightl` or `heghtg` is immediately reflected. the heightl and heightg are for each texture.

These textures can be upto 4K 4096X4096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a varying variable between your vertex and fragment shader. A single float value should suffice, since you're only interested in the height coordinate.

Other than that, introduce 5 uniform varaiables for your textures in the fragment shader and do the calculations on the GPU.

In more detail:

For each fragment you get in the fragment shader the interpolated height value of the current mesh. Depending on the height value you simply select the sample from the desired texture and put that color out.

Comment: Actually I think I need to process the texture in cpu side as this is not just for showing but also should be baked and saved to a png or some other format

Comment: Also one more thing I took 5 as an example it is variable so if I follow your approach u won't be able to go for more than 32 textures dur
E to gpu limit

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee What you do 'after' the calculations is not important, the way to go there is what we're discussing. `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` (`glGetIntegerv`) tells you how many texture units you can use at once (see https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader#Resource_limitations).

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee Btw. you can also render into a texture, if you want to process the image further.

Comment: I guess i will go with the second idea

Comment: If you exceed the GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, implement multiple render steps, you only have to upload the textures once, and download the final image if you want to store it in a file. GPU will solve your problem faster than the CPU (and from my understanding, what you're describing can be solved completely on the GPU).

Comment: I agree to that but for now for simplicity sake i will limit max texture count

Comment: `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` gives you the max size of either dimension. On my (middle aged) system that is 16K. So you could use one large texture which is tiled with your level textures. Well, that means an additional operation in the shader, but in your case (4K) that would mean 16 height level textures in one texture.